# how to append to a list dynamically

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a complex list in python with the general structure described as follows.

The outer list is a normal list of the form `[index1, index2, index3, ...]`

and each index in the list has the following structure:

```
[a, b, [[c, d], [e, f], [g, h], ...]
```

The values of `c, d, e, f, etc` are supposed to correspond to the values of `a and b` and should be unique to the index, so there shouldn't be repetition unless `a and b` are repeated.

The code I have to try to implement this is:

```
a = []
b = []

for i in range(4):
    a.append([i,i])
    b.clear()
    for j in range(6):
        b.append([i,j])
    a[i].append(b)
```

And the output I get when printing each index:

```
[0, 0, [[3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5]]]
[1, 1, [[3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5]]]
[2, 2, [[3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5]]]
[3, 3, [[3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5]]]
```

As observed, the output only contains data from the final index. I can tell that the `b.clear()` is the reason for this, but I would think that since I'm appending to a before clearing the previous index's data, it would not cause this behaviour.

Comment: How can you tell that `b.clear()` is the reason the output only contains data from the final index?

Comment: you need to create a copy of the list using `b.copy()` while appending to `a`. try with `a[i].append(b.copy())`

Comment: Creating the copy worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's not the `clear` that's necessarily causing the problem, but because you're reusing the array `b` declared at the same level as `a`.  Moving the initialization of `b` into the loop (and even keeping the `clear`) gives you the behavior you expected.

```
a = []

for i in range(4):
    a.append([i, i])
    b = []
    b.clear()
    for j in range(6):
        b.append([i, j])
    a[i].append(b)
```

Output

```
[0, 0, [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [0, 5]]]
[1, 1, [[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5]]]
[2, 2, [[2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5]]]
[3, 3, [[3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5]]]
```